# SlidingPaneLayout (v4) master pane выглядит как выделенный

Tags: android

В SlidingPaneLayout (v4) master pane состоит из ListView и кнопок управления. Когда detail pane открыт, master pane выглядит словно мышкой выделили. Можно ли как-нибудь избавиться от этого эффекта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конечно, можно.